# TensorFlow [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a Unidirectional RNN for sequence modeling and neural embedding. I have built a custom class to experiment with various architectures and parameters. The data manager class in the code is another class that basically reads text data, processes it and converts it into numeric vectors. tf_train_set is tensorSliceDataset containing numeric vectors and labels of 60% of the dataset. rest 40% are in tf_valid_set.
I have the following code for my RNN:

```
class UniRNN:
    def __init__(self, cell_type= 'gru', embed_size= 128, state_sizes= [128, 64], data_manager= None):
        self.cell_type = cell_type
        self.state_sizes = state_sizes
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.data_manager = data_manager
        self.vocab_size = self.data_manager.vocab_size +1 
        
    #return the correspoding memory cell
    @staticmethod
    def get_layer(cell_type= 'gru', state_size= 128, return_sequences= False, activation = 'tanh'):
        if cell_type=='gru':
            return tf.keras.layers.GRU(state_size, return_sequences=return_sequences, activation=activation)
        elif cell_type== 'lstm':
            return tf.keras.layers.LSTM(state_size, return_sequences=return_sequences, activation=activation)
        else:
            return tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(state_size, return_sequences=return_sequences, activation=activation)
    
    def build(self):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None])
        h = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embed_size, mask_zero=True, trainable=True)(x)
        num_layers = len(self.state_sizes)
        for i in range(num_layers):
            h = self.get_layer(self.cell_type, self.state_sizes[i], return_sequences=True)(h)
        h = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dm.num_classes, activation='softmax')(h)
        self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=h)
    
    def compile_model(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model.compile(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def evaluate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model.evaluate(*args, **kwargs)
```

To fit the model, my code is:

```
uni_rnn = UniRNN(cell_type='basic_rnn', embed_size=128, state_sizes=[128, 128], data_manager=dm) #Insert your code here
uni_rnn.build()
# uni_rnn.model.summary()
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
uni_rnn.compile_model(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
uni_rnn.fit(dm.tf_train_set.batch(64), epochs=20, validation_data = dm.tf_valid_set.batch(64))
```

when I run this code, I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-abef9ae0cbcd> in <module>
      3 opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
      4 uni_rnn.compile_model(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 5 uni_rnn.fit(dm.tf_train_set.batch(64), epochs=20, validation_data = dm.tf_valid_set.batch(64))

<ipython-input-170-53f4c12769ab> in fit(self, *args, **kwargs)
     31 
     32     def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 33         return self.model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
     34 
     35     def evaluate(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    340                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    341                 training_context=training_context,
--> 342                 total_epochs=epochs)
    343             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    344 

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    126         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    127       try:
--> 128         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    129       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    130         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     96     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     97     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 98                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     99 
    100   return execution_function

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    566         xla_context.Exit()
    567     else:
--> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    569 
    570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    630         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    631         # stateless function.
--> 632         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    633     else:
    634       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2361     with self._lock:
   2362       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2363     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2364 
   2365   @property

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1609          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1610                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1611         self.captured_inputs)
   1612 
   1613   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1690       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1691       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1692           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1693     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1694         args,

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543               inputs=args,
    544               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 545               ctx=ctx)
    546         else:
    547           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~\anaconda3\envs\myenv_tf21_p37\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (loss/dense_13_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ] [64 1] [y (loss/dense_13_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0) = ] [64 100]
     [[node loss/dense_13_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert (defined at <ipython-input-170-53f4c12769ab>:33) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_111597]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Can someone please explain what the problem is? and maybe how I can fix it?

Comment: dm.num_classes in this case is 6

Comment: your target is 2D?

Comment: could you explain what you mean when you say 2D?

Comment: (n_sample, n_classes) ? or (n_sample,) ?

Comment: (n_sample, n_classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last RNN in the loop must have return_sequence = False. to do this you can simply do:

```
def build(self):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None])
    h = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embed_size, 
                                  mask_zero=True, trainable=True)(x)
    num_layers = len(self.state_sizes)
    for i in range(num_layers-1):
        h = self.get_layer(self.cell_type, self.state_sizes[i], return_sequences=True)(h)
    h = self.get_layer(self.cell_type, self.state_sizes[i], return_sequences=False)(h)
    h = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dm.num_classes, activation='softmax')(h)
    self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=h)
```

Comment: could you please explain as to why it is so?

Comment: becausue your target is 2D and if the last lstm/gru returns a sequence you are producing a 3D output